# Python beautiful soup: is it soup.findAll, or soup.find_all?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

There seems to be a great deal of confusion in regards to this method from beautiful soup 4 or bs4. [As you can see in my link here,](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/72td1z/comment/dnl55ja?st=J83CVIPB&sh=7d8ceefahttps://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/72td1z/comment/dnl55ja?st=J83CVIPB&sh=7d8ceefa) on Reddit, there is a difference of opinion in which to use. I was recommended some code from someone off of Reddit, and used it. Only to have someone point out later that it should be different. So I don’t know which one is correct. Any insight?